How do I take my bicycle to one of the islands outside Zadar?
I just tried taking my bicycle on the Jadrolinija ferry from Zadar to Preko  but they wouldn't allow me to bring it.
Are there any other of the islands outside Zadar to which a ferry company will let me bring a bicycle?

Did they explain why they wouldn't allow it?  Are you certain it wasn't just because the bicycle facilities on the ferry were fully occupied at the time?

The Jadrolinija website shows that a bicycle ticket from Zadar to Preko costs €3.50.  Did they refuse to sell you a bicycle ticket or refuse to let you board because you didn't have one?  Or something else?

@phoog they flat out refused to let me bring it, before even checking my ticket. I think the issue is that there's one ferry for pedestrians and one for vehicles. I was on the one for pedestrians. That's what my research so far indicates, at least.

Turns out I was on the wrong ferry. The one that goes from Zadar Port Saint
Chrysogonus Gate will take strictly pedestrians. Ticket fare €5
The one that goes from Zadar Port will take all kinds of vehicles. It's also bigger and more comfortable. Ticket fare €3.50 and €3.50 extra for a bicycle. The only downside is that the port is outside the city center. But with a bicycle it only took me 15 minutes.

